# JAVAFX not being picked up in runtime from Spring STS with Java 8 on Mac

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, runtime, java-8, spring-tool-suite

I've installed Java 8 and Spring STS on Mac. Running jjs from the command line works. However, when trying to create a new class in a Maven project in STS, the editor doesn't recognise the javafx.* package automatically.

Attached you'll find an example of an image showing that the only Label object suggested is the java.awt one.

Any idea on how I could solve this?

Regards,
M.

[image]

Comment: I think when working with non-maven project you would need to install and use efx tooling [+] to make eclipse 'JavaFX aware' and add javafx stuff to your project's classpath. Unfortunately I do not know if/how that would work for maven projects. [+] = https://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/install.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is related to the settings of your project. If your project is created with an execution environment JavaSE-1.8, this execution environment doesn't have the javafx API defined as accessible and you would need to manually allow that. If you choose the 1.8 JRE (as a JRE, not an execution environment) in your project settings, the JavaFX API is accessible and works nicely in content-assist, quick fix, etc. This is at least the case if you create a standard Java project.